# GitLab : iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-cloud-storage, git-merge

We are trying to submit a merge request in git lab and we started suddenly facing below error :
Error: git@gcp.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)

I have referred all the bucket storage permissions and i do see we have "storage.objects.get" role and service account has Storage Object Admin permissions which is already been assigned but when the merge request is been submitted in Git Lab
we are facing below error

```
Error: git@gcp.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)
```

I have referred below links and tried all the ways but still facing error :

```
https://acloudguru.com/forums/gcp-certified-associate-cloud-engineer/accessdeniedexception-403-amit-bf-kumargmail-com-does-not-have-storage-buckets-get-access-to-the-google-cloud-storage-bucket

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385902/service-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-access-to-the-google-cloud-sto

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402934/accessdeniedexception-403-does-not-have-storage-buckets-get-access-to-the-googl
```

None of the solution worked. Any suggestion pls. Pls let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: try to review this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410633/service-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-access-for-google-cloud-storag?rq=1), and try simulate the answer of @Drux,  I suspected that the service account was associated with too many roles.

Comment: if you resolve your issue, you can post your answer below, to help other communities for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After adding below 2 roles the problem is resolved and able to submit the merge request.

Thanks a lot to @Jeffrey D for the reference link

```
Cloud Storage - Storage Admin
Cloud Storage - Storage Object Creator
```