# does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-cloud-storage, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am trying to download sales report via python code. Here's my code:

```
import json

from httplib2 import Http

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

from apiclient.discovery import build

# Change these variables to fit your case

client_email = 'nameofserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

json_file = '/Users/xxx/Downloads/key.json'

cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXX'

report_to_download = 'earnings/earnings_XXXXX.zip'

 
private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')

storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

try:
    response = storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket, object=report_to_download).execute()
    print(response)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

and i get this error:
`<HttpError 403 when requesting https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXX/o/earnings%2Fearnings_XXXXXXX.zip?alt=json returned "nameofserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).". Details: "[{'message': "nameofserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">`

Here are other details:

1. My service account has the following permission: Storage Admin and Storage Object Admin
2. I have tried deleting and creating my service account, still the same issue.
3. I have tried editing descriptions of my in app products, still the same issue.
4. Cloud Storage API is enabled.
5. I tried removing the Storage Admin role from your service account and then add it again.
6. I tried giving the service account the Storage Object Viewer role separately.

This used to work when API access was still accessible in Settings in Google Play Console. For some reason, Google did an update on how to add API access and this does not work anymore.

Comment: can you try adding `Storage Object Creator` also,have a look at this  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225723/gitlab-iam-gserviceaccount-com-does-not-have-storage-buckets-get-access-to-the) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410633/service-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-access-for-google-cloud-storag?rq=1) which might help

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I've tried that as well no luck. I checked ur link2 suggestion, im not sure how to add permission to the bucket. As the bucket where the reports are available are not being shown in the Cloud Storage > Bucket section

Comment: As mentioned in this [thread](https://serverfault.com/a/1063784) try adding `roles/storage.legacyBucketReader` Also check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) & [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Service-account-stopped-working/m-p/513416?nobounce)